# Magento 404 Security Question

Tags: url-rewrite, security, 404

I have a Magento 404 question:

This generic product url looks like this 
http://www.domain.com/some-magento-product.html

But from a security standpoint.  how would a request to something like this be treated:

GET /bulkhead-abs-thread-x-thread-1-45713f6ff2041d3fdfae927b82488db8.html+Result:+%E8%F1%EF%EE%EB%FC%E7%F3%E5%EC+SOCKS+192.168.0.90:10045;+%E8%F1%EF%EE%EB%FC%E7%EE%E2%E0%ED+%ED%E8%EA%ED%E5%E9%EC+%22aidajy1%22;+

Now, I know on the apache level that a 404 appears to be generated and the client is served your generic ‘not found’ page.

But, would/could Magento itself act on that request in addition to the 404 that’s seen at the client end?

Comment: Why did someone downvote this question? What did I do wrong?

Comment: No idea, it's a good & legit question from my point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This request would make it to Magento (if SEO URL rewrites are enabled):

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/.htaccess#L169

The URL Encoded string has some funky characters most likely in hopes of escaping and attempting to connect to a local socket `192.168.0.90:10045` with some argument of `aidajy1`

```
���������� socks 192.168.0.90:10045; ����������� ������� "aidajy1";
```

If you are worried about someone accessing, it would be wise to start tailing log files and doing some code audits and grep scans over the FS to see if theres any possible back doors installed.

Is a pretty common signature, but realize there are countless ways, so take the search with a grain of salt or as use case example:

Locate eval(gzinflate [common signature for hiding backdoors/exploits] recursively for PHP exploits (all file types)

```
find . -type f -name '*' -printf '"%p"\n' | xargs grep --no-messages -l "eval*(gzinflate" --color
```

Comment: Thanks @BOOMER - I ran your command and got a xargs error at first, I added the -printf and it worked.